# manifest.json being linked as preload in DevTools, even though it's not

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, manifest.json

I have a plain `<link
rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json">` on my site. Strangely, Chrome's DevTools is warning:

> The resource mysite.com/manifest.json was preloaded using link
>   preload but not used within a few seconds from the window's load
>   event. Please make sure it has an appropriate `as` value and it is
>   preloaded intentionally.

Not sure why manifest.json is being preloaded. Any clues?

Comment: Can you put a demo up on [Glitch](https://glitch.com) that reproduces the problem?

Comment: @KayceBasques Here's a demo of what's going on: [link](https://v4.eclectiv.com/)  I reduce the code down to the bare bones to make things easier to troubleshoot.

Comment: Thanks for the demo. I can reproduce the issue. Have you tried setting the [MIME type of the manifest file](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Manifest#Mime_type) on your server?

Comment: I just added the MIME type to my server config (see below), but that didn't resolve the problem.

```<IfModule mod_mime.c>

    AddType application/manifest+json                webmanifest

</IfModule>```